# Fetch data from SQL table using Join with additional column according to Join

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have to tables those are connected with foreign key relation

`Address` Table

```
id | address| country
1  | xyz    | USA
2  | xyz    | IND
```

`Employee` Table

```
id | name |  company | Postal_address | Visiting_address
1  | Test |  xyz     |     1          |   2
```

How can I display Linked address to Employee using a SQL query like

```
Address  | Country |  Address Type
xyz      |   USA   | Postal
xyz      |   IND   | Visting
```

Is their any possible way to display linked address of any employee as list with Address type name using a SQL Server query or C#?

Comment: We're keen to help, the keyword being help - not do it all for you. So show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: based on what are you generating address type, in other word, how do you get address type ?

Comment: @Saif  Based on `Postal_address` and `Visiting_address`. Check my answer below Bro.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQL UNION and UNION ALL Keywords](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp) to achieve it, Live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfb763dbec2ef443131ef31024961564)

```
DECLARE @Address AS TABLE(id int, address varchar(50), country varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Address
VALUES(1, 'xyz', 'USA'),
      (2, 'xyz', 'IND')

DECLARE @Employee  AS TABLE(id int, name varchar(50), company varchar(50), Postal_address int, Visiting_address int)
INSERT INTO @Employee
VALUES(1,'Test',  'xyz', 1,  2)

SELECT a.address, a.country, 'Postal' AS Address_Type
FROM @Employee e
INNER JOIN @Address a on a.id = Postal_address
WHERE e.id = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT a.address, a.country, 'Visting' AS Address_Type
FROM @Employee e
INNER JOIN @Address a on a.id = Visiting_address
WHERE e.id = 1
```

**Output**

```
address country Address_Type
xyz     USA     Postal
xyz     IND     Visting
```

Comment: This query does't work with condition, I want to see address for one specific employee from a list of employees

Comment: So you should add `Where` clause to filter. For example `Where Employee.id = 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @pankash mann

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with UNPIVOT. [Read more on UNPIVOT](https://expert-only.net/sql-server/sql-server-unpivot-function/). 
The sample code is given below for reference.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #address (
    id INT
    ,address VARCHAR(255)
    ,country VARCHAR(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE #Employee (
    id INT
    ,name VARCHAR(20)
    ,company VARCHAR(20)
    ,Postal_address INT
    ,visiting_address INT
    );

INSERT INTO #address
VALUES (1   ,'xyz'  ,'USA') ,(  2   ,'xyz'  ,'India');

INSERT INTO #Employee
VALUES (    1   ,'test' ,'xyz'  ,1  ,2  );

WITH CTE_AddressUnpivot
AS (
    SELECT name
        ,address_Type
        ,address_id
    FROM (SELECT *
        FROM #Employee
        ) AS src
    UNPIVOT(address_id FOR address_Type IN ([postal_Address], [visiting_address])) AS addressUnpivot
    )
SELECT addr.address
    ,addr.country
    ,CASE unp_addr.address_Type
        WHEN 'Postal_address' THEN 'Postal'
        WHEN 'visiting_address' THEN 'Visiting'
        END AS Address_Type
FROM #address AS addr
JOIN CTE_AddressUnpivot AS unp_addr ON addr.id = unp_addr.address_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with `LEFT JOIN`s and `COALESCE`, like below:

```
declare @Address table (id int, address varchar(10), country varchar(10));
insert into @address values
(1,'xyz','USA'),
(2,'xyz','IND');
declare @Employee table (id int, name varchar(10),company varchar(10),Postal_address int,Visiting_address int);
insert into @employee values
(1, 'Test', 'xyz', 1, 2);

select a.address, a.country,
       case when ePost.id is not null then 'Postal'
            when eVisit.id is not null then 'Visiting'
            else null end AddressType
from @address a
left join @employee ePost on a.address = ePost.company and a.id = ePost.Postal_address
left join @employee eVisit on a.address = eVisit.company and a.id = eVisit.Visiting_address
```